Make error when compiling the latest stable linux kernel 6.12.y
I am new to linux kernel dev. So, following the course "A Beginner's guide to Linux Kernel Development (LFD103)" by Linux Foundation.
I have checked that my system satisfies the minimal requirements and followed the instructions in the course to install the latest 6.12 kernel.
But getting an error in line 1937 and 224 while using the make command.
Getting the following error:
make[1]: *** [/home/hariharan/linux_work/linux_stable/Makefile:1937: .] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:224: __sub-make] Error 2


Attached Logs for reference below: Any help to troubleshoot the following error will be really grateful. 

 mkdir -p /home/hariharan/linux_work/linux_stable/tools/bpf/resolve_btfids && make O=/home/hariharan/linux_work/linux_stable subdir=tools/bpf/resolve_btfids --no-print-directory -C bpf/resolve_btfids 
mkdir -p /home/hariharan/linux_work/linux_stable/tools/objtool && make O=/home/hariharan/linux_work/linux_stable subdir=tools/objtool --no-print-directory -C objtool 
  INSTALL libsubcmd_headers
  INSTALL libsubcmd_headers
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=. need-builtin=1 need-modorder=1 
  AS      arch/x86/lib/clear_page_64.o
make[3]: *** No rule to make target 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:478: certs] Error 2
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      lib/math/div64.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/generic_mpih-lshift.o
  CC      lib/math/gcd.o
  CC      lib/math/lcm.o
  CC      lib/math/int_log.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/cmdline.o
  CC      lib/math/int_pow.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/cmpxchg16b_emu.o
  CC      lib/math/int_sqrt.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/copy_mc.o
  CC      lib/math/reciprocal_div.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/generic_mpih-mul1.o
  CC      lib/math/rational.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/copy_mc_64.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/copy_page_64.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/generic_mpih-mul2.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/copy_user_64.o
  CC [M]  lib/math/cordic.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/generic_mpih-mul3.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/copy_user_uncached_64.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/cpu.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/generic_mpih-rshift.o
  AR      lib/math/built-in.a
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/generic_mpih-sub1.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/generic_mpih-add1.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpicoder.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/csum-copy_64.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/csum-partial_64.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/csum-wrappers_64.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/delay.o
  CC      lib/crypto/memneq.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpi-add.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/error-inject.o
  CC      lib/crypto/utils.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/getuser.o
  GEN     arch/x86/lib/inat-tables.c
  CC      arch/x86/lib/insn-eval.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpi-bit.o
  CC      lib/crypto/chacha.o
  CC      lib/crypto/aes.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/insn.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpi-cmp.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/kaslr.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/memcpy_64.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpi-sub-ui.o
  CC      lib/crypto/aescfb.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/memmove_64.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/memset_64.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/misc.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/pc-conf-reg.o
  CC      lib/zlib_inflate/inffast.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpi-div.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/putuser.o
  CC      lib/zlib_inflate/inflate.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/retpoline.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpi-mod.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/usercopy.o
  CC      lib/zlib_inflate/infutil.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpi-mul.o
  CC      lib/zlib_inflate/inftrees.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/usercopy_64.o
  CC      lib/zlib_inflate/inflate_syms.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpih-cmp.o
  AR      lib/zlib_inflate/built-in.a
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpih-div.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/msr-smp.o
  CC      lib/crypto/gf128mul.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/cache-smp.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/msr.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpih-mul.o
  CC      lib/crypto/blake2s.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpi-pow.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/msr-reg.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/msr-reg-export.o
  CC      lib/crypto/mpi/mpiutil.o
  AS      arch/x86/lib/hweight.o
  CC      lib/zlib_deflate/deflate.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/iomem.o
  AR      lib/crypto/mpi/built-in.a
  CC      lib/crypto/blake2s-generic.o
  CC      lib/zlib_deflate/deftree.o
  CC      arch/x86/lib/inat.o
  CC      lib/crypto/sha1.o
  AR      arch/x86/lib/built-in.a
  AR      arch/x86/lib/lib.a
  CC      lib/lzo/lzo1x_compress.o
  CC      lib/zlib_deflate/deflate_syms.o
  CC      lib/crypto/sha256.o
  CC      lib/lzo/lzo1x_decompress_safe.o
  AR      lib/zlib_deflate/built-in.a
  CC      lib/lz4/lz4_decompress.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/libchacha.o
  AR      lib/lzo/built-in.a
  CC      lib/zstd/zstd_compress_module.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/arc4.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/fse_compress.o
  CC [M]  lib/lz4/lz4_compress.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/hist.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/huf_compress.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/chacha20poly1305.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/curve25519-hacl64.o
  CC [M]  lib/lz4/lz4hc_compress.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_compress.o
  AR      lib/lz4/built-in.a
  CC      lib/xz/xz_dec_syms.o
  CC      lib/xz/xz_dec_stream.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/curve25519-generic.o
  CC      lib/xz/xz_dec_lzma2.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_compress_literals.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_compress_sequences.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/curve25519.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_compress_superblock.o
  CC      lib/xz/xz_dec_bcj.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/des.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_double_fast.o
  CC [M]  lib/xz/xz_dec_test.o
  AR      lib/xz/built-in.a
  CC      lib/dim/dim.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/poly1305-donna64.o
  CC [M]  lib/crypto/poly1305.o
  CC      lib/dim/net_dim.o
  LD [M]  lib/crypto/libarc4.o
  LD [M]  lib/crypto/libchacha20poly1305.o
  LD [M]  lib/crypto/libcurve25519-generic.o
  LD [M]  lib/crypto/libcurve25519.o
  LD [M]  lib/crypto/libdes.o
  LD [M]  lib/crypto/libpoly1305.o
  AR      lib/crypto/built-in.a
  CC      lib/fonts/fonts.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_fast.o
  CC      lib/dim/rdma_dim.o
  CC      lib/fonts/font_8x8.o
  CC      lib/fonts/font_8x16.o
  AR      lib/dim/built-in.a
  CC      lib/pldmfw/pldmfw.o
  CC      lib/fonts/font_acorn_8x8.o
  CC      lib/fonts/font_6x10.o
  CC      lib/fonts/font_ter16x32.o
  AR      lib/fonts/built-in.a
  CC [M]  lib/842/842_compress.o
  AR      lib/pldmfw/built-in.a
  CC [M]  lib/reed_solomon/reed_solomon.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_lazy.o
  CC [M]  lib/842/842_decompress.o
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/algos.o
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/recov.o
  HOSTCC  lib/raid6/mktables
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow-memchr.log
  UNROLL  lib/raid6/int1.c
  UNROLL  lib/raid6/int2.c
  UNROLL  lib/raid6/int4.c
  UNROLL  lib/raid6/int8.c
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/recov_ssse3.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow-memchr_inv.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow-memcmp.log
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/recov_avx2.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow-memscan.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow2-memcmp.log
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/mmx.o
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/sse1.o
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/sse2.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow2-memcpy.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow2-memmove.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow2_field-memcpy.log
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/avx2.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/read_overflow2_field-memmove.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow-memcpy.log
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/avx512.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow-memmove.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow-memset.log
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/recov_avx512.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow-strcpy-lit.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow-strcpy.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow-strncpy-src.log
  TABLE   lib/raid6/tables.c
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/int1.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow-strncpy.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow-strscpy.log
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/int2.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow_field-memcpy.log
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow_field-memmove.log
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/int4.o
  TEST    lib/test_fortify/write_overflow_field-memset.log
  CAT     lib/test_fortify/test_fortify.log
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/int8.o
  CC      lib/argv_split.o
  CC      lib/bug.o
  CC [M]  lib/raid6/tables.o
  CC      lib/buildid.o
  LD [M]  lib/raid6/raid6_pq.o
  CC      lib/clz_tab.o
  CC      lib/cmdline.o
  CC      lib/cpumask.o
  CC      lib/ctype.o
  CC      lib/dec_and_lock.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_ldm.o
  CC      lib/decompress.o
  CC      lib/decompress_bunzip2.o
  CC      lib/zstd/compress/zstd_opt.o
  CC      lib/zstd/zstd_decompress_module.o
  CC      lib/zstd/decompress/huf_decompress.o
  CC      lib/zstd/decompress/zstd_ddict.o
  CC      lib/decompress_inflate.o
  CC      lib/decompress_unlz4.o
  CC      lib/decompress_unlzma.o
  CC      lib/zstd/decompress/zstd_decompress.o
  CC      lib/decompress_unlzo.o
  CC      lib/zstd/decompress/zstd_decompress_block.o
  CC      lib/zstd/zstd_common_module.o
  CC      lib/decompress_unxz.o
  CC      lib/decompress_unzstd.o
  CC      lib/dump_stack.o
  CC      lib/earlycpio.o
  CC      lib/zstd/common/debug.o
  CC      lib/zstd/common/entropy_common.o
  CC      lib/zstd/common/error_private.o
  CC      lib/zstd/common/fse_decompress.o
  CC      lib/extable.o
  CC      lib/zstd/common/zstd_common.o
  CC      lib/flex_proportions.o
  CC      lib/idr.o
  AR      lib/zstd/built-in.a
  CC      lib/irq_regs.o
  CC      lib/is_single_threaded.o
  CC      lib/klist.o
  CC      lib/kobject.o
  CC      lib/kobject_uevent.o
  CC      lib/logic_pio.o
  CC      lib/maple_tree.o
  CC      lib/memcat_p.o
  CC      lib/nmi_backtrace.o
  CC      lib/objpool.o
  CC      lib/plist.o
  CC      lib/radix-tree.o
  CC      lib/ratelimit.o
  CC      lib/rbtree.o
  CC      lib/seq_buf.o
  CC      lib/siphash.o
lib/maple_tree.c: In function ‘mas_wr_spanning_store’:
lib/maple_tree.c:3794:1: warning: the frame size of 1040 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
 3794 | }
      | ^
  CC      lib/string.o
  CC      lib/timerqueue.o
  CC      lib/union_find.o
  CC      lib/vsprintf.o
  CC      lib/win_minmax.o
  CC      lib/xarray.o
  CC      lib/lockref.o
  CC      lib/bcd.o
  CC      lib/sort.o
  CC      lib/parser.o
  CC      lib/debug_locks.o
  CC      lib/random32.o
  CC      lib/bust_spinlocks.o
  CC      lib/kasprintf.o
  CC      lib/bitmap.o
  CC      lib/scatterlist.o
  CC      lib/list_sort.o
  CC      lib/uuid.o
  CC      lib/iov_iter.o
  CC      lib/clz_ctz.o
  CC      lib/bsearch.o
  CC      lib/find_bit.o
  CC      lib/llist.o
  CC      lib/lwq.o
  CC      lib/memweight.o
  CC      lib/kfifo.o
  CC      lib/percpu-refcount.o
  CC      lib/rhashtable.o
  CC      lib/base64.o
  CC      lib/once.o
  CC      lib/refcount.o
  CC      lib/rcuref.o
  CC      lib/usercopy.o
  CC      lib/errseq.o
  CC      lib/bucket_locks.o
  CC      lib/generic-radix-tree.o
  CC      lib/bitmap-str.o
  CC      lib/string_helpers.o
  CC      lib/hexdump.o
  CC      lib/kstrtox.o
  CC      lib/iomap.o
  CC      lib/iomap_copy.o
  CC      lib/devres.o
  CC      lib/check_signature.o
  CC      lib/btree.o
  CC      lib/interval_tree.o
  CC      lib/assoc_array.o
  CC      lib/bitrev.o
  CC      lib/linear_ranges.o
  CC      lib/packing.o
  CC      lib/crc-ccitt.o
  CC      lib/crc16.o
  CC      lib/crc-t10dif.o
  HOSTCC  lib/gen_crc32table
  HOSTCC  lib/gen_crc64table
  CC      lib/crc64-rocksoft.o
  CC      lib/xxhash.o
  CC      lib/genalloc.o
  CC      lib/textsearch.o
  CC      lib/percpu_counter.o
  CC      lib/iommu-helper.o
  CC      lib/error-inject.o
  CC      lib/syscall.o
  CC      lib/dynamic_debug.o
  CC      lib/errname.o
  CC      lib/nlattr.o
  CC      lib/cpu_rmap.o
  CC      lib/closure.o
  CC      lib/dynamic_queue_limits.o
  CC      lib/glob.o
  CC      lib/digsig.o
  CC      lib/strncpy_from_user.o
  CC      lib/strnlen_user.o
  CC      lib/net_utils.o
  CC      lib/sg_pool.o
  CC      lib/memregion.o
  CC      lib/irq_poll.o
  CC      lib/stackdepot.o
  CC      lib/bootconfig.o
  CC      lib/asn1_decoder.o
  CC      lib/asn1_encoder.o
  GEN     lib/oid_registry_data.c
  CC      lib/ucs2_string.o
  CC      lib/ubsan.o
  CC      lib/sbitmap.o
  CC      lib/group_cpus.o
  CC      lib/fw_table.o
  CC [M]  lib/test_bpf.o
  CC [M]  lib/test_blackhole_dev.o
  CC [M]  lib/crc-itu-t.o
  CC [M]  lib/crc4.o
  CC [M]  lib/crc7.o
  CC [M]  lib/libcrc32c.o
  CC [M]  lib/crc8.o
  CC [M]  lib/bch.o
  CC [M]  lib/ts_kmp.o
  CC [M]  lib/ts_bm.o
  CC [M]  lib/ts_fsm.o
  CC [M]  lib/notifier-error-inject.o
  CC [M]  lib/pm-notifier-error-inject.o
  CC [M]  lib/memory-notifier-error-inject.o
  CC [M]  lib/lru_cache.o
  CC [M]  lib/polynomial.o
  CC [M]  lib/parman.o
  CC [M]  lib/objagg.o
  AR      lib/lib.a
  GEN     lib/crc32table.h
  GEN     lib/crc64table.h
  CC      lib/oid_registry.o
  CC      lib/crc32.o
  CC      lib/crc64.o
  AR      lib/built-in.a
make[1]: *** [/home/hariharan/linux_work/linux_stable/Makefile:1937: .] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:224: __sub-make] Error 2

Also, I saw that I shouldn't get any emerg, crit, err and alert messages from dmesg. I copied the messages to a text file after installing the latest stable kernel. I didn't see any emerg, crit or alert messages, but the err file was populated with the following text. Should I worry about it?
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/dswloa> 
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220) 
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PC00.DGPV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/p> – 
integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65 i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: 
Transaction timeout i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: 
Failed terminating the transaction i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4:   
SMBus is busy, can't use it!   
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs> 
ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/> 
Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02


Does Compiling kernel 5.11.11 and later help? The referenced answer is on the subject of fixing the same 'debian/canonical-certs.pem', needed by 'certs/x509_certificate_list' error as reported in this question.

Disabling the SYSTEM_TRUSTED_KEYS & SYSTEM_REVOCATION_KEYS variable solved that issue. Now the kernel is compiling for more than 45 minutes with couple of warnings alone. Thank you for the quick response.
But disabling those two variables is the recommended approach?

Yes, disabling those two things is the recommended approach for compiling test kernels for personal use and development.

Also, I saw that I shouldn't get any emerg, crit, err and alert messages from dmesg. I copied the msgs to text file after installing the latest stable kernel. I didn't see any emerg, crit or alert messages but err file was populated with following  text. should i worry about it?
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/dswloa>
ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20230628/psobject-220)
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PC00.DGPV], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/p>

Continuation of error msgs:
integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Transaction timeout
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: Failed terminating the transaction
i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus is busy, can't use it!
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_TZ.ETMD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs>
ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.IETM._OSC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/>
Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
